# How to wire USB-C connector?

Tags: layout, kicad, usb-c

I am trying to add USB-C to an ESP32 module. I am using a `[CP2102][1]`

This is the USB-C connector I was planning to use, simply because JLCPCB has tons of them and can SMD solder it: (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2103051833_Jing-Extension-of-the-Electronic-Co--918-418K2023S40001_C167321.pdf):
[image]

I think it matches in Kicad with `Connector_USB:USB_C_Receptacle_HRO_TYPE-C-31-M-12`
[image]

This is the best I could come up with, but since they are differential pairs, not sure if it will work:

[image]
[image]

Are there any examples on how can I route D- and D+?

Are there any other connectors that would make this easier?

[EDIT]

I built the device. It works very well, so if you are reading this, go ahead and copy it.

I also have another version using an IC instead of the diodes, it also worked.

 You can find both detailed versions including KiCad files in the following link:
https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[USB Type-C spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf) states (Table 3-4, note 1, p. 68):

> In one implementation, Dp1 and Dp2 may be shorted on the host/device as close to the receptacle as possible to minimize stub length; Dn1 and Dn2 may also be shorted. The maximum shorting trace length should not exceed 3.5 mm.

Here, this Type-C routing looks typical. Traces seem to be in spec (you should probably measure them to be sure).

There are no easier SMD connectors as they all have the same problem: expose 4 pins connected two-by-two that come from two lines with opposed order (because of Type-C layout symmetry).

Even hybrid THT/SMD connectors like [Amphenol 10133476-10001LF](https://cdn.amphenol-icc.com/media/wysiwyg/files/drawing/10133476.pdf) do not leave enough space between pins to let routing happen on one layer only (and is overkill for your application).

Comment: Thanks @Nipo! Does that means traces have to have less than 3.5mm difference? Kicad says that one is 8.66 and the othe rone 11.01.

Comment: It’s not about difference, but about extra track length between both D+ (or both D-) pins that will act as a stub when connector is using one of the two polarities.